# Session is not replicating in websphere memory to memory replication

Tags: java, session, websphere

I am replicating memory to memory session replication Webshpere over IHS, accessing application with the IHS. There are two nodes, after one node is down session is not replicating to second node. Verified cookie is same before and after node down.

```
jsessionid=0001B1d0q3ty911xyrAzwUhB0lXwb:-1OG411T9:1eeskro311e     
Node 1 cookie, now after down this node.

req.getSession(false) -- giving null    

jsessionid=0001B1d0q3ty911xyrAzwUhB0lXwb:-1OG411T9:1eeskro311e     
Node 2, verified from access logs.
```

Please suggests what I am missing.

Below are the WASSession logs.

```
7a WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new session context for application key default_host/Custom
[8/20/20 10:25:47:794 IST] 0000007a WASSession    I MTMStore setDRSMode SESN0188I: Memory To Memory mode for application default_host/Custom is BOTH
[8/20/20 10:25:47:795 IST] 0000007a WASSession    I MTMStore setDRSMode SESN0188I: Memory To Memory mode for application default_hostCustom is BOTH
```

Comment: Did you setup m2m replication  on both servers? It is not configured by default.

Comment: Yes.. it is properly configured.

Comment: Do you have cluster configured? or 2 separate servers? The m2m replication usually just works, so it must be something in your configuration which is not correct.

Comment: We are getting session in one iframe, but when request is going from one ifram to other iframe it is not working. These iframes are present in parent application with different context. eq: Application A having iframes and session is lost in B application.

Comment: There is no session sharing between apps. So your app A has its own session and app B other session. You cannot reach data in other app session. Also your session cookies might get overwritten, so I'd try to change cookie name in the session management for each app and test. Like jsessionIDA and jsessionIDB.

Comment: Tried this also, still the same issue.

Comment: Adding more info... application A and B, we are testing failover and when request from app A(parent app) is going on node 1 and request from app2 is going on node 2, now node 2 is down. In this case session is not replicating when request is going from app1 to app2